# Adding dynamic drop down components in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, selectonemenu

My requirement is like this. I have a selectMenu with some values (Examples: Engineering, Medicine, Law etc..,) . Suppose if I select Engineering in the drop down, I want another dropdown menu created dynamically which has values related to Engineering (Example: Electronics, Computers, Electricals etc..,). How do I achieve this in JSF 2.0 ?

Comment: Check our `[selectonemenu]` wiki page for more hints how to get most of those components: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info (you can access it by hovering the `[selectonemenu]` tag which I placed below your question until a black box shows up and then clicking therin the *info* link).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to perform an ajax request when first `h:selectOneMenu`'s selection change. This request will update the selectable items in the second `h:selectOneMenu`. After the ajax request, you must render the second `h:selectOneMenu` again, with the updated values.

**Page:**

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.selectedSubject}">
    <f:ajax listener="#{bean.changeSubject}" render="speciality_selection" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.subject}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>

<h:selectOneMenu id="speciality_selection" value="#{bean.selectedSpeciality}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.subjectSpecialities}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

**Managed bean:**

```java
public void changeSubject(){
    //Loads the specialities depending on the selected subject
    subjectSpecialities = loadSpecialitiesForSubject(selectedSubject);
}
```