# jsf update drop down menu

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have two drop down menus, and the content of the second depends on the choice in the first one. Now, the content changes but only after I hit "refresh". It needs to change automatically on selection of the first menu.

```
<h:outputLabel value="Country: " />
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.country}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="-- select country --" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="Spain" itemLabel="Spain" />
    (...)
    <f:ajax listener="#{bean.findCity}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>

<h:outputLabel value="City: " />
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.city}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="-- select city --" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.citiesFound}" var="city" 
        itemLabel="#{city.cityNameFull}" itemValue="#{schedule.cityName}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Again, the function findCity works fine, because the result is correct when I refresh the page, but I want the second menu to refresh automatically.

Comment: Give the second selctOneMenu an id and use render attribute of f:ajax.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding dynamic drop down components in JSF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609660/adding-dynamic-drop-down-components-in-jsf)